# Сборка проекта с внешними библиотеками

Tags: сборка, java, jar, компиляция

Здравствуйте.

Работаю в NetBeans 7.3.1 и захотелось мне мой проект в .jar файл собрать,вроде собрал,но при запуске в консоли вижу ошибки связанные с отсутствием внешней библиотеки.

Как собрать проект со всеми библиотеками?

Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В эклипсе всё просто!
File -> Export -> Runnable JAR File.
В NetBeans - должно быть по аналогии.

Answer (score 1):

См. [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) или [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) на худой конец.